# how to find avg of referenced schema field in mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have schema designed like this

```
const MerchantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    mobile: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    user_type:{
        type:String,
        enum:['merchant'],
        required: true
    },
    isVerified:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:()=>false
    },
    token:String,
    location:{
        type:{
            type:String,
            enum:['Point'],
            default:()=>'Point'
        },
        coordinates:{
            type:[Number],
            required:true
        }
    },
    images:[String],
    reviews:[{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'reviews'
    }],

});
MerchantSchema
    .method("toJSON", function() {
        const { __v, _id, ...object } = this.toObject();
        object.id = _id;
        return object;
  });
MerchantSchema.index({location:'2dsphere'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('merchants',MerchantSchema);
```

review schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ReviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    rating:{
        type:Number,
        required:true,
        default:0
    },
    message: {
        type: String,       
        required: true
    },
    owner_id:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'merchants'
    },
    posted_by:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'users',},
});
ReviewSchema
  .method("toJSON", function() {
      const { __v, _id, ...object } = this.toObject();
      object.id = _id;
      return object;
}); 
module.exports = mongoose.model('reviews', ReviewSchema);
```

i want to get result based on geoLocation and with some condition
and i want additional field of avgRating in the result set.
i am trying with following query

```
try {
        
    const merchants = await Merchant.aggregate([
        // match merchant lat lng in radius
        {
            $geoNear: {
                near: {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: [
                        parseFloat(req.query.long),
                        parseFloat(req.query.lat)
                    ]
                },
                distanceField: "distance",
                maxDistance: Number(req.query.distance),
                spherical: true
            },
        },
        { $match: { isActive: { $eq: true } } },
        // {
        //     $unwind: {
        //       path: "$reviews"
        //     }
        //   },
        {
            $addFields: {
              reviewCount: {
                $size: "$reviews"
              },
              avgRating: {
                $avg: "$reviews.rating",
              }
            }
          },
          // uncoment this to get all data except the reviews
          {
            $project: {
                reviews: 0,
            }
          },
        // uncomment this to get all the reviews withth slected fields
        // if selected fields are not required then comment let section 
        // and pipeline section and uncomment local fiels and foreign fields
        // {
        //     $lookup: {
        //         from: "reviews",
        //          let: { owner_id: "$_id" },
        //          pipeline: [ 
        //              {$match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$owner_id", "$$owner_id" ] } } },
        //              { $project: { message: 1, posted_by: 1, _id: 0,rating:1 } } 
        //          ],
        //         as: "reviews",
                  
        //     }
        // },
        
    ]);
    return (merchants.length>0)?
            apiResponse.successResponseWithData(res,"Success",merchants) :
            apiResponse.ErrorResponse(res,{message:"No merchants found"});
    
     
} catch (error) {
    return apiResponse.ErrorResponse(res, error.message || "Some error occurred while getting merchants.");
}
```

output i am getting is

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "6223400356a5f3404b57a273",
            "mobile": 9999999999,
            "user_type": "merchant",
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    25.75679373274295,
                    86.02907103277855
                ]
            },
            "images": [],
            "isVerified": true,
            "__v": 0,
            "reviewCount": 2,
            "facilityCount": 2,
            "avgRating": null
        }
    ]
}
```

expecting output

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "6223400356a5f3404b57a273",
            "mobile": 9999999999,
            "user_type": "merchant",
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    25.75679373274295,
                    86.02907103277855
                ]
            },
            "images": [],
            "isVerified": true,
            "__v": 0,
            "reviewCount": 2,
            "facilityCount": 2,
            "avgRating": 3.0
        }
    ]
}
```

what are the possibilities of getting the expecting outputs.
any suggestion would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine with me. I tried it on my own database. Below is the example.

```
db.Merchant.aggregate([
  {
    $geoNear: {
      near: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [
          25.75679373274295,
          86.02907103277855
        ]
      },
      distanceField: "distance",
      maxDistance: 10,
      spherical: true
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      isActive: {
        $eq: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "reviews",
      let: {
        owner_id: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$owner_id",
                "$$owner_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            message: 1,
            posted_by: 1,
            _id: 0,
            rating: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "reviews"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      reviewCount: {
        $size: "$reviews"
      },
      avgRating: {
        $avg: "$reviews.rating"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      reviews: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lAj4wdPtEPO)